# Zebra card printer through C#.NET code

Tags: c#, printing, system.drawing, zebra-printers

I have developed a C#.NET application to print cards, and it works in a Fargo DTC 1000 printer.
Now I've changed my printer (a Zebra ZXP series 3) for the same purpose, printing cards (only text), but it's not working.
I always get the error "Creck the ribbon", but I've changed it.
The printer works fine if I send to print from notepad.

The app communicates through LAN with the printer which is being shared in a server.
APP-->Server-->Computer-->Printer

In conclusion, the code works and the printer works, also I reach the printer through the code. The problem is that I can't get it work through the code.

I'm using System.Drawing API.

Please, I ended up with all my ideas.
Thank you in advance!

This are the main methods.

```
public void Print()
    {
        if (Parameter == null)
            throw new Exception("No existen parametros para la impresión");

        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument
                               {
                                   DefaultPageSettings =
                                       {
                                           Landscape = true,
                                           Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)
                                       },
                                   PrinterSettings = {PrinterName = Parameter.PrinterName}
                               };
        pd.PrintPage += pd_PrintPage;

        pd.Print();
    }

    private void pd_PrintPage(Object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        Font printFont = new Font("Arial", FontSize, FontStyle.Bold);
        SetDataToPrint(Parameter.IdMovItem);

        ev.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Inch;

        ev.Graphics.DrawString(Data.Asegurado, printFont, Brushes.Black, Parameter.AseguradoX, Parameter.AseguradoY,
                               new StringFormat());

        ev.HasMorePages = false;
    }
```

Comment: Does your Zebra printer require the use of the ZPL language for printing?

Comment: I suspect this thread may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044676/net-code-to-send-zpl-to-zebra-printers?rq=1

Comment: @Alex how can I know if my printer require ZPL language? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You **have** to use the [SDK](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SA264&actp=LIST) provided by Zebra Technologies. The Zebra printers don't work like normal printers. I had to actually use their SDK and print by using the driver over USB connect. Information is very vague when it comes to the ZXP3 and everything is kind of *as-is*. Good luck.