# How to Print Label Design in Zebra Designer 2.0 Using C#?

Tags: c#, printing, zebra-printers

I am stuck in printer related issue,I have to designed and print 4 by 6 label with Zebra Series printer,my client have different series of zebra printer from which i have GC420t Series at my desk.
   So I have download Zebra Designer v2.0 in which i had designed label,but in realtime scenario i have to print that label with my MVC C# Project.
after net searching i got link as follow

[.NET code to send ZPL to Zebra printers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044676/net-code-to-send-zpl-to-zebra-printers)
[.NET code to send ZPL to Zebra printers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044676/net-code-to-send-zpl-to-zebra-printers)

which is not suitable as per need. can any one suggest me to move on right direction.
I am getting code only for andriod/smartphones/IOS/mobile platform

Comment: Please clarify not suitable as per need.  The links have C# code for direct printing to windows, such as connected / installed windows printer drivers.  If your intention is to have the Android, iOS, other mobile to print to a Zebra printer, I can only assume you mean when they use their device, it is force triggered to a web-based MVC C# project and you want to print from your local web-serving machine and not the actual source device.  Again, please clarify the environment / conditions for printing.

Comment: Mean i need to print  "*.lbl"  Extension file, Which built using zebra designer  v2.0 app. we do same thing with tool also like Neodynamic , bartender tool thermal printer they provide there own C# SDK. for printing label.but in case of Zebra designer  i haven't fount C# Sdk Code.

Comment: Almost 10 years later but ... did you find the solution @sunnybarmota ? How do one print labels made with Zebra Designer?