# How to print a label in local ZPL printer from hosted site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, printing, zpl, neodynamic

I have hosted my site in remote machine. I can able to access that site in any machine through online link (ex: xyz.mysite.com). I need to print a label from that online site. I have write a below code to print a label (Used Neodynamic thermal SDK library in my application).

```
var pj = new PrintJob();    
PrinterSettings myPrinter = new PrinterSettings();
                           myPrinter.Communication.CommunicationType = CommunicationType.Network;
                           myPrinter.Communication.NetworkIPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); // Used my local network IP address.
                           myPrinter.Communication.NetworkPort = 9100;
                           myPrinter.UseDefaultPrinter = true;
                           myPrinter.ProgrammingLanguage = ProgrammingLanguage.ZPL;
                           pj.PrinterSettings = myPrinter;
                           pj.Print(myLabel);
```

When I perform print action in web site, facing below error,

> An exception occurred while getting the default printer. Win32 error:
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

Can anyone suggest me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48915919/7782179)

Answer (score 0):

i develop a websockt for this cases [ZPLwebSocket](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vse4zhsYnPhSoJ6HqyzfhOWYm9PeqEyP)

1. Download the file and uncompress.
2. Run SetUp.exe on client PC.
3. Go to services and start 'Servicio de Impresion desde Navegador'
4. open trysocket.html with GoogleChrome or mozilla
5. write the name of local printer
6. click on button 'enviar'
7. show the messages of server

   this is javascriptcode on page.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {  var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:2645/service/');  const reader = new FileReader();

     $('.sendZPL').on('click', function () {

       var tosend = {
         TipoArchivo: 0,
         nombre: "Etiqueta de Prueba",
         code: $(".sendZPL").val(),
         Tipo: 4,
         Impresora: $(".impresora").val()
       }
       connection.send(JSON.stringify(tosend));
     });

     connection.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
       reader.readAsText(event.data);
     });

     reader.addEventListener('loadend', (e) => {
       const text = e.srcElement.result;
       console.log(text);
       $(".serverResponse").val(text);
     });

   });
   ```

this is the socket code c# for run on ConsoleApp:

```
class Program
{

    private static Server.WebsocketServer websocketServer;
    private static System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog1= new EventLog();
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists( "MySource" ))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                "MySource", "MyNewLog" );
        }

        eventLog1.Source = "MySource";
        eventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog";


        websocketServer = new Server.WebsocketServer();
        websocketServer.LogMessage += WebsocketServer_LogMessage; 

        websocketServer.Start( "http://localhost:2645/tryservice/" );

        Console.Read();
    }



    private static void WebsocketServer_LogMessage( object sender, Server.WebsocketServer.LogMessageEventArgs e )
    {
        // eventLog1.WriteEntry( e.Message );
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine( e.Message );
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }
public  class WebsocketServer
{
    public event OnLogMessage LogMessage;
    public delegate void OnLogMessage(Object sender, LogMessageEventArgs e);
    public class LogMessageEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public LogMessageEventArgs(string Message) {
            this.Message = Message;
        }
    }

    public bool started = false;
    public async void Start(string httpListenerPrefix)
    {
        HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();
        httpListener.Prefixes.Add(httpListenerPrefix);
        httpListener.Start();
        LogMessage(this, new LogMessageEventArgs("Listening..."));
        started = true;

        while (started)
        {
            HttpListenerContext httpListenerContext = await httpListener.GetContextAsync();
            if (httpListenerContext.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                ProcessRequest(httpListenerContext);
            }
            else
            {
                httpListenerContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                httpListenerContext.Response.Close();
                LogMessage(this, new LogMessageEventArgs("Closed..."));
            }
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        started = false;
    }

    private List<string> _printers = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Printers { get
        {
            _printers.Clear();
            foreach (string imp in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
            {
                _printers.Add(imp);
            }
            return _printers;
        }
    }

    private async void ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext httpListenerContext)
    {
        WebSocketContext webSocketContext = null;

        try
        {
            webSocketContext = await httpListenerContext.AcceptWebSocketAsync(subProtocol: null);
            LogMessage(this, new LogMessageEventArgs("Connected"));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            httpListenerContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            httpListenerContext.Response.Close();
            LogMessage(this, new LogMessageEventArgs(String.Format("Exception: {0}", e)));
            return;
        }

        WebSocket webSocket = webSocketContext.WebSocket;
        try
        {


            while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {

                ArraySegment<Byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new Byte[8192]);

                WebSocketReceiveResult result = null;

                using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
                        ms.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, result.Count);
                    }
                    while (!result.EndOfMessage);

                    ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
                    {
                        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
                        {
                            var r = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                            var t = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Datos>(r);
                            bool valid = true;
                            byte[] toBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Error..."); ;

                            if (t != null)
                            {
                                if (t.Impresora.Trim() == string.Empty)
                                {
                                    var printers = "";
                                    Printers.ForEach(print => {
                                        printers += print + "\n";
                                    });

                                    toBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("No se Indicó la Impresora\nLas Impresoras disponibles son:\n" + printers);
                                    valid = false;
                                }
                                else if(!Printers.Contains(t.Impresora))
                                {
                                    var printers = "";
                                    Printers.ForEach(print =>
                                    {
                                        printers += print + "\n";
                                    });

                                    toBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Impresora no valida\nLas Impresoras disponibles son:\n" + printers);
                                    valid = false;
                                }


                                if (t.nombre.Trim() == string.Empty)
                                {
                                    toBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("No se Indicó el nombre del Documento");
                                    valid = false;
                                }
                                if (t.code== null)
                                {
                                    toBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("No hay datos para enviar a la Impresora");
                                    valid = false;
                                }


                                if (valid && print.RawPrinter.SendStringToPrinter(t.Impresora, t.code, t.nombre))
                                {
                                    LogMessage(this, new LogMessageEventArgs(String.Format("Enviado: {0} => {1} => {2}", t.Impresora, t.nombre, t.code)));
                                    toBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Correcto...");
                                }

                                await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(toBytes, 0, int.Parse(toBytes.Length.ToString())), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);


                            }
                            else
                            {
                                toBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Error...");
                                await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(toBytes, 0, int.Parse(toBytes.Length.ToString())), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogMessage(this, new LogMessageEventArgs(String.Format("Exception: {0} \nLinea:{1}", e, e.StackTrace)));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (webSocket != null)
                webSocket.Dispose();
        }
    }


}

public class Datos {
    public enum TipoArchivo { zpl, pdf, doc, json, text}
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public TipoArchivo Tipo { get; set; } = TipoArchivo.text;
    public string Impresora { get; set; } = "";
}


}
```

the RAWPrinterClass [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12842174/7782179):

```
 public class RawPrinter
    {
        // Structure and API declarions:
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public class DOCINFOA
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDocName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pOutputFile;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDataType;
        }
        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
string szPrinter, ref IntPtr hPriknter, IntPtr pd);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
DOCINFOA di);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, ref Int32 dwWritten);

        // SendBytesToPrinter()
        // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
        // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
        // Returns true on success, false on failure.
        public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, string DocName = "")
        {
            Int32 dwError = 0;
            Int32 dwWritten = 0;
            IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
            DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
            bool bSuccess = false;
            // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.
            di.pDocName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(DocName) ? "My C#.NET RAW Document" : DocName;
            di.pDataType = "RAW";

            // Open the printer.
            if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), ref hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                // Start a document.
                if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
                {
                    // Start a page.
                    if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                    {
                        // Write your bytes.
                        bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, ref dwWritten);
                        EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                    }
                    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
            // about why not.
            if (bSuccess == false)
            {
                dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            return bSuccess;
        }

        public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
        {
            // Open the file.
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
            // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
            bool bSuccess = false;
            // Your unmanaged pointer.
            IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
            int nLength = 0;

            nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
            // Read the contents of the file into the array.
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
            // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
            pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
            // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
            bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
            return bSuccess;
        }
        public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString, string DocName = "")
        {
            IntPtr pBytes = default(IntPtr);
            Int32 dwCount = default(Int32);
            // How many characters are in the string?
            dwCount = szString.Length;
            // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
            // the string to ANSI text.
            pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
            // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
            var t= SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount, DocName);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
            return t;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used [TLClientPrint](https://www.neodynamic.com/demo-faq/thermal-label-sdk-net/asp.net-client-side-cross-browser-barcode-thermal-label-printing-with-thermalLabel-sdk.aspx.) to resolve my problem.