# Zebra Printer to print QR code label in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, printing, zebra-printers

I generated the QR code and I want to print the QR code directly from this method without javascript.
I tried with javascript. It's not printing properly. I will get a base64 image in the result variable. Please help to find out the solution.

```
public ContentResult GeneratQRCode(string ID)
{
    string result;
    try
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
            QRCodeGenerator.QRCode qrCode = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(ID, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
            Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(40, 40);
            using (bitMap = qrCode.GetGraphic(2))
            {
                bitMap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

                result = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
           
            }

        }
        return Content(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = "Exception";
        return Content(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you converting to Base64?  The printer wants a byte[] array.

Comment: I want to print the QR code

Comment: You want to print a png file. It is not important what image is in the stream.  The printer is looking for a byte array not a string.

Comment: Yes, the printer looking for a byte array. but I  did not get any library in ASP.NET MVC to print from this method.

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044676/net-code-to-send-zpl-to-zebra-printers

Comment: Generate proper ZPL code for printing QR code and your problems are gone