# Zebra s600 print script

Tags: c#, zebra-printers

This is my first try to create a c# script to print a label from a Zebra s600 printen. I have a really hard time finding a good guide on the internet about how this would work. The Zebra s600 is also a very old model. Right now I am using the SDK from Zebra:

https://www.zebra.com/gb/en/support-downloads/printer-software/link-os-multiplatform-sdk.html#text_f34a

But I found out that the s600 is not included in the support list. My script does activated a little greenlight on the printer the moment I run the script. But nothing else happens. I also have no idea how to search further for my issue. Every search is a dead end.

I did followed this tutorial because I could't find any example on the web:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvWG9_rE9rg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it still supports ZPL.  Have you tried sending `~WC`?  Try opening a command prompt and doing `echo ~WC > LPT1` or `echo ~WC > COM1`.

If that prints a config label, then you can either use the [ZDesigner drivers](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/eula/unrestricted-eula.-227178c9720c025483893483886ea54032da4ba1a754ef88faaff03fffc08a71d3935761544249a3ee398d678e1882a06ca654fd4c1199d56a08d8bef9c305481299b8950e32f7b.html) to print to it as a [normal windows printer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).  If you do not find a driver for the exact model of printer, just select one with the same DPI and PDL.

Or [you can write ZPL directly to the printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044676/net-code-to-send-zpl-to-zebra-printers).  To figure out what ZPL to send, you can [use ZebraDesigner](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/print-dna/zebra-designer.html).  The free versions are sufficient.  Avoid the XML functionality unless you find the printer to support it - it was introduced after that series, I think.

Comment: The ZPL method worked for me. I printed i little example label. Now trying the designer for a real label. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: UPDATE: Yesterday I could finally print a label using ZPL. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @NielsLucas, glad to hear it.