# Getting Printer Status using TSPL/TSPL2 and C#

Tags: c#, zebra-printers, tspl

I'm using the [RawPrinterHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12842174/8533874) to send data to my printer (Elgin L42 DT), but i'm not being able to receive the printer Status. I've tried the status polling from the [TSLP](http://www.kroyeuropedownload.com/English_User_Manuals/TSPL_TSPL2_Programming_Jan_2017.pdf) but receive nothing back from the printer. There is a way to get the printer status?