# Print QR code from Blazor Server app to Zebra

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, zebra-printers

I need to print a 2D QR code from a blazor server side app. I've used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12842174/13826315) but *PrintDialog* is not working even after adding **System.windows.Forms**. Any idea on how to do it. My printer is **GK420T** connected to USB001.

Answer (score 0):

- First, add the following package to your Blazor server app project: 
  `Zebra.Sdk.Printer`
- Next, create a new C# class called LabelPrinter with the following code:

  ```
  using Zebra.Sdk.Comm;
  using Zebra.Sdk.Printer;
  using Zebra.Sdk.Printer.Discovery;

  public class LabelPrinter
  {
    private Connection printerConnection;
    private ZebraPrinter printer;

    public LabelPrinter(string ipAddress)
    {
      printerConnection = new TcpConnection(ipAddress, TcpConnection.DEFAULT_ZPL_TCP_PORT);
      printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.GetInstance(printerConnection);
    }

  public void PrintQRCode(string data, int x, int y, int size)
  {
    var qrCodeCommand = "^BQ,2,10^FDMA," + data + "^FS";
    var qrCodeSizeCommand = "^BY" + size.ToString();
    var qrCodePositionCommand = "^FO" + x.ToString() + "," + y.ToString();

    var labelCommands = new StringBuilder();
    labelCommands.AppendLine("^XA");
    labelCommands.AppendLine(qrCodePositionCommand);
    labelCommands.AppendLine(qrCodeCommand);
    labelCommands.AppendLine(qrCodeSizeCommand);
    labelCommands.AppendLine("^XZ");

    printerConnection.Open();

    if (printerConnection.Connected)
    {
        printerConnection.Write(labelCommands.ToString());
    }

    printerConnection.Close();
    }
   }
  ```

PrintQRCode method takes in the data to be encoded in the QR code, as well as the X and Y coordinates and size of the QR code.

The method creates the ZPL command for printing the QR code using the ^BQ command, and sets the data and size using the ^FD and ^BY parameters. It also sets the position of the QR code using the ^FO parameter.

Finally, the method constructs the full label commands using the StringBuilder class, and sends them to the printer over the network using the Write method.

Next, in your Blazor server app, create a new razor component called PrintLabel with the following code:

```html
@page "/printlabel"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<h1>Print Label</h1>

<label for="label-content">Label Content:</label>
<textarea id="label-content" @bind="LabelContent"></textarea>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="PrintLabel">Print</button>

@code {
    private string LabelContent { get; set; }
    private async Task PrintLabel()
    {
        var printer = new LabelPrinter("192.168.0.100"); // Replace with your printer's IP address
        printer.PrintQRCode(LabelContent, 100, 100, 10);

        await NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
}
```

Comment: To which namespace Printer does belong?

Comment: I don't understand your question ?

Comment: There is a declaration `Private Printer printer`, it does not belong to the Zebra SDK. So what else should I import or install?

Comment: Belonge to `Zebra.Sdk.Printer`

Comment: It is giving me errors, I am using `using Zebra.Sdk.Printer;`

Comment: Sorry for this error, try `ZebraPrinter ` class instead of `Printer ` !

Comment: See: 
https://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/2-12/webservices/content/com/zebra/sdk/printer/zebraprinter

Comment: Still errors in text area, need to solve it before.

Comment: Can you write which error do you have ?

Comment: `The name 'LabelContent' does not exist in the current context` and `The type or namespace name 'LabelPrinter' could not be found`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add, check it a gain.

Comment: Did you check it?

Comment: Not working, cannot establish connection to printer.

Comment: Which error did you get?